# Robots create robots in this movie. Also, they are a threat to humanity

Tags: story-identification, robots, horror, artificial-intelligence

There was a movie that I watched once in my childhood(around 15 years ago).
There were robots creating other robots.
Some brains (green colored) in enclosed shells (filled with a transparent liquid).
And they are a threat to the human race.

I just cant recall anymore.
Can you please help me with the name of this movie.

Comment: Where were the brains? Were they on top of the robots or floating around on their own.

Comment: Was it animation art or a live action movie?

Comment: Could it be Terminator?

Comment: Was it a comedy? I'm not sure about robots creating other robots, but the brains in enclosed shells makes me think of _Mars Attacks!_ from 1996 (my god is that movie really twenty years old?!?!). - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116996/

Comment: I think the brains were on top of robots. 
No, its not Mars Attacks; I've seen it. Seen all Terminator movies; I, Robot etc.

Answer (score 5):

Could it be the loose adaptation of Asimov's works, the Will Smith version of "I, Robot".

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0343818/

It certainly has robots building robots, and various times when the robots glowing brains are exposed and a climactic scene with a large robot brain.

Will Smith's character even makes a direct reference to "Robots building robots" in a rather cringeworthy line.

> Robots building robots. Now that's just stupid.

Comment: The movie is only 12 years old though.

Comment: That's around-ish 15 years. It didn't sound exact from the question.

Comment: 12 years is 15 years +/- 25%. Close enough to my mind.

Answer (score -1):

The movie can be 'Automata'.
Here is the link of its trailer.

Comment: This came out in 2014. The OP said they watched it about 15 years ago.